# Apple Notes: Moving a Quick Note into a folder always fails the first time

Tags: notes.app

When trying to move a Quick Note into one of the other folders in Apple Notes, it never works the first time for me: first it appears to work as intended, but after a few seconds, the note just appears back in the Quick Note folder.
If I drag it into the other folder a second time, it will stay there.

I suspect this is related to some issue with iCloud syncing.

Has anyone encountered the same and managed to fix this?

---

More Details:
M1 Mac running latest version of Sonoma
I tried both dragging the notes from the gallery view of the Quick Notes folder into the left sidebar and also right clicking the note and using "Move to".